# Problem with arguments in Bash in console

Tags: bash, scripting, positional-parameter

I have a Big problem and I don't know how can I solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
function prueba(){
        valor=$1
        echo "Hola ${valor}"
}
prueba $valor
```

so, when i write in the console:

```
./beta1.sh prueba 123
```

print:

```
Hola
```

I expected to see:

```
Hola 123
```

Comment: Replace `$valor` with `$2`?

Comment: Within the prueba function $1 is the first parameter passed to the function. Your script is calling prueba with $valor which is undefined.

Comment: `$1` is only the _first_ argument. You're passing two arguments, not one -- and in a function, `$1` refers to the first argument _to the function_, not the first argument _to the script_. Because _until after the function has been run_ `valor` is empty, the function is passed no arguments at all as currently written.

Comment: Consider `prueba "$*"`

Comment: BTW, `function` is bad form; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (there are entries about it in multiple tables; read them both). Better to just write `prueba() { ...` with no leading `function`.